# comparing an arrayList to itself

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

If i have an `arrayList` (for simplicity sake) that contains `A,B,C`

and i want to compare these values against themselves without comparing anything to itself and without comparing the same two values twice...

how would i do this?

right now i have the following

```
for(Double db : arrayList)
{
    for(Double db2 : arrayList)
    {
        if(db2 != db)
        {
            //compare
        }
    }
}
```

but this does not eliminate the case where first A is compared to B and then later B is compared to A ...

any ideas?

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you probably just want to go by *index* instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size() - 1; i++) {
    Double db = arrayList.get(i);
    for (int j = i + 1; j < arrayList.size(); j++) {
        Double db2 = arrayList.get(j);

        // Don't use == unless you *really* want reference identity
        if (!db2.equals(db)) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`subList(int fromIndex, int toIndex)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList%28int,%20int%29):

```
List<Double> arrayList = ...;
int length = arrayList.size();

for(int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++)
{
    Double db1 = arrayList.get(i);
    for(Double db2 : arrayList.subList(i + 1, length))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can make the bound for `i` one less here, as the last element won't have anything to be compared to. (The sublist would be empty.)

Comment: @JonSkeet Doesn't `arrayList.subList(length, length)` return an empty list, hence it won't go into the inner-loop?

Comment: Yes, but my point is that you *know* it'll do that - so why even go into the *outer* loop, fetch the last element and then create the empty sublist (view)?